# Dynamically Adding a lot of controls in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a simple foreach statement that creates a usercontrol and adds it to a stackPanel control (see code below). Products is just a List of int's.

```
 foreach (int id in Products)
 {
   ItemControl itemControlProduct = new ItemControl (id );
   this.StackPanelControl.Children.Add(itemControlProduct);
 }
```

This works fine if the List has about 50 items (Products), but once it goes over, my application refuses to render. (i.e no exceptions occurs, windows task manger says program is running properly, but yet no window appears)

How can I solve this problem. I need to load over 600 items. p.s I dont want to use pagination. I want all elements to be listed at once.

Comment: Did you consider using databinding and/or a VirtualizingStackpanel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StackPanel is not the parent control you're looking for. Use ListView, which utilizes a virtualizing panel ([VirtualizingStackPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.aspx)) and has a lot of goodies, such as events for selecting things, changing the looks without changing the logic behind etc.

The "virtualizing" part means that there are only a limited number of UI controls that are rendered at runtime, regardless how many items you've placed in the container.

There are many ways it can be done, the sample below is just a sample with the least amount of assumptions:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ...your binding to Products}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
<GridViewColumn Width="100">
    <GridViewColumnHeader>
        <TextBlock Text="Item"/>
   </GridViewColumnHeader>
   <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemControl ItemId="{Binding Path=id}"/> <!-- this is for Product.id, you'll have to change it-->
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer, but I'd strongly advise against this "code-behind" way of working with controls. WPF is geared around data binding. Create a view model that contains your 600 items in a collection and let WPF do the hard work.

Consider using an `ItemsControl` with `ItemsPanel` set to a `VirtualizingStackPanel`. This will ensure controls are only created as and when they become visible. Bind the `ItemsSource` property to your collection.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyModel.MyCollection}">
 <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
   <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
 </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```